# What should be the relationship between an adminstrators table and users table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, entity-relationship

If admin account can create user accounts, does this mean that the relationship between the admin table and the users table is:

> ADMIN OneToMany Users

For example, in my project:
[image]

A person with the privilege **adminstrateur** account, can create accounts with the privilege **technicien_sav**. Obviously, each kind of **privilege** grants the one who has it access to different parts of the app.
However, I do not see the SQL relationship necessary for the overall functioning of my app. I.e: The **administrateur** can create **technicien_sav** accounts even without the existence of the relationship between the two.
What do you think?
**PS:** It's been years since I've worked with SQL databases, I hope the question is not too naive.

Comment: Why would you have multiple tables. A role is an attribute of User much like Admin is an attribute of User

Comment: You want to store which administrator created which user?

Comment: No, in my project, they have absolutely nothing to do with each other! Basically, there's the admin who manages the app and who can create accounts for the technicians who are the 'users'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you said the admin and technician users

> have absolutely nothing to do with each other

Their real-world jobs might be different, but in terms of your application they're just two different variations of a user, so they belong in the same table (because they are the same kind of entity, a "user" of the application, and each table should represent an entity). The fact they are "admin" is just a property of the user, which differentiates them from the other type(s). You can then use that property (and others, if you need more subtlety) to determine what privileges they have within the application.

It's not uncommon in fact, for users to hold multiple sets of privileges, so therefore a many-to-many relationship between a "users" table and a "privileges" table (with a mapping table in between, of course) might make more sense and be more flexible in the long term.

P.S. To address your original point, in your suggested original structure you'd only need some relationship between the admin and technician rows if you needed to record which admin created which records. You could still do the same thing in a single "users" table if you needed to, by simply having a one-to-many relationship between two columns in the same table. e.g. you'd have a CreatedBy column which would be optional, and would have a foreign key to the ID column, so it could record the ID of the user who added the current record.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for clearing this up and pointing me to the next step to solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

in general, admin and user are part of the same table.

Admin is a user with more privilege. In your user table you can add a column (admin_column for example and can be boolean) so if admin_column=true (the user is an administrator).

I hope it will help you.

Comment: No, in my project, they have absolutely nothing to do with each other!

Comment: Basically, there's the admin who manages the app and who can create accounts for the technicians who are the 'users'.

Comment: it's a java web application ?

Comment: @AhmedGhrib "they have absolutely nothing to do with each other"..their real-world jobs might be different, but in terms of your application they're just two different variations of a user, so they belong in the same table (because they are the same kind of entity, a "user" of the application, and each table should represent an entity). The fact they are "admin" is just a property of the user, which differentiates them from the other type(s). You can then use that property (and others, if you need more subtlety) to determine what privileges they have within the application.

Comment: @ADyson That's what I needed to hear

Comment: @AhmedGhrib It's not uncommon in fact, for users to hold multiple sets of privileges, so therefore a many-to-many relationship between a "users" table and a "privileges" table (with a mapping table in between, of course) might make more sense and be more flexible in the long term. And to address your original point, in your suggested original structure you'd only need some relationship between the admin and technician rows if you needed to record which admin created which records.

Comment: Thank you! But, if I would need that record and both the admin and the technician are the same entity then it would be a recursive relationship?

Comment: @AhmedGhrib I made a formal answer which includes a response to this last point as well.